# View Updating Model directly In WPF MVVM instead of ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

This is the link i am following for learning MVVM in WPF and i have a question:-
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/mvvm_first_application.htm

DataContext of the WPF window is set to a VIEWMODEL object.
Itemsource of a List-DataTemplate is set to a List from the same VIEWMODEL Object.
The Model contains an implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged.
When i update the view,the INotifyPropertyChanged of MODEL gets fired ie VIEW is directly updating the MODEL while what i have understood till now is that VIEW interacts with the VIEWMODEL only via Bindings and Commands and never with the MODEL DIRECTLY.It is always the ViewModel which interacts with the Model to fetch data for the View.But here,the View is updating the Model DIRECTLY.This is confusing me owing to my limited knowledge.
Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

If the view model exposes the model through a property, the view may actually bind directly to the model through this property. This doesn't really violate the MVVM pattern and is perfectly fine, especially if the model class implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. If it does, you can say that the model is kind of a (child) view model.

A "real" model such as a domain object or a service shouldn't have any knowledge about WPF and how you raise change notifications to a view. Therefore it rarely makes sense to bind directly to such objects but if your models are "WPF aware" and implements view related interfaces, you can bind to them without any issues.

Comment: Imho the view accessing the model partially violates the pattern as you don't have separation of concerns any more. It this is right with a List why can't the view has as DataContext a model object?

Comment: @Ignacio Soler Garcia, I guess you should read my answer again. You are saying that "the correct approach would be always to create a ViewModel of that Model (the list element) and bind to it". That's what he already has done if the model implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't agree. The responsibilities of a Model and a ViewModel are completely different and are not related with implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. In fact INotifyPropertyChanged has nothing to do  with WPF.

Comment: You don't agree with what? Your own answer?

Comment: I don't agree with: "That's what he already has done if the model implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface".

Answer (score 0):

It is a common error to bind the `Model` thru lists to the `View`. The correct approach would be always to create a `ViewModel` of that `Model` (the list element) and bind to it.

For example:

[image]

Otherwise you are opening the door to including data on `ModelB` that should be stored in the `ViewModelB`.

Comment: Can u create a View,ViewModel and Model of the same tutorial to help me understand your explanation better?

Comment: Imagine that ModelA has a List<ModelB>. Instead of making that list available in ViewModelA you would add a List<ViewModelB> in ViewModelA. If it is still unclear ask again I will try to find another way.

Comment: The link u provided is broken

Comment: Hi once again Ignacio.I wrote some code but it is pretty long to be posted here.Can u gimme some email id where i can post my code to you and help me know whether i have understood correctly or not.Basically,in my code,View is updating only and only the ViewModel and ViewModel takes that data to and from the Model back and forth.No interaction between View and Model directly.I have used INotifyPropertyChanged on ViewModel and Model while notifying of any change back and forth.

Comment: Sounds good. What about posting in https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: sorry for the delay ignacio.I have posted the code here:-
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162025/simple-mvvm-create-update-delete-records-using-wpf
Please suggest me whether if i have understood it correctly.Help me improvise.

Comment: I replied, by the way, up voting is the way to thank the help ... :)